# $\mathbb{R}$ with usual $+$, but not multiplication

Tags: field-theory, real-numbers

I want to find a field whose elements are the real numbers, whose addition is defined the usual way, but which is not isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$ because of a different multiplicative group. Does this engender a contradiction, or can one construct such a thing?

Thanks!

Comment: Which axioms of $\mathbb R$ do you want to uphold? http://www-history.mcs.st-and.ac.uk/~john/analysis/Lectures/L5.html

Comment: nothing about ordered fields, merely regarding the reals as elements

Comment: The multiplication has to be the same on the natural numbers since $a\cdot b=(1+1+...+1)\cdot(1+1+...+1)=1+1+...+1$, with the usual number of ones. Therefore, it also has to be the same on the rationals. By the same argument it has to be the same between rationals and irrationals.

Comment: @treeleaf Yes, it has to be the same on the rationals, but if you drop completeness axiom it doesn't have to be on the irrationals.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Assuming the axiom of choice, the additive group of $\Bbb R$ is isomorphic to the additive group of $\Bbb C$, so we can take this isomorphism and pull back the multiplication from $\Bbb C$.

Comment: And how do we prove the multiplication from $\mathbb{C}$ is not isomorphic to the one from $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: @TStancek $i$ is an element of order $4$ in the multiplicative group of $\Bbb C$, whereas the only elements of finite order in the multiplicative group of $\Bbb R$ are $1$ and $-1$

Comment: Thanks, just wasn't that straightforward for me. And might not be for some others.